# How to validate a form and check if each question is answered?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

the questions are saved in database. In order for the users to see the questions, it is looped as well as the answers. (i don't know if I explain this right)

I will provide the whole code for the form, I really don't know what to do with this one. What I am trying to achieve is user cannot click next or submit if the questions are left unanswered. But this code, even if the user is not answering and just clicking next and submit, it will do submit. so it ends up the user can have 0 score which should not be the case.

```
    <form action="applicantAssessmentSave.php" method="post" id="register_form">

       <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="finished_degree" style="color:#fff";>Finished Degree</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="finished_degree" id="finished_degree"   onchange= "handleSelectChange(event)" required>
         <option value="" selected disabled >Select your finished degree</option>
         <option value="BSIT">BSIT</option>
         <option value="BSHM">BSHM</option>
         <option value="BSBA">BSBA</option>
        </select>
      </div>
                                            
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function handleSelectChange(event){
         var selectElement = event.target;
         var value = selectElement.value;

            $.ajax({
                url:"degree_job_match.php", 
            type: "post",    
            data: {
                "value": $('#finished_degree').val(),
            }, 
            success:function(data){
            }
        });
     }
    </script>
    </div>
        <?php
            $m = 1;
            $query = mysqli_query($con, "select * from question_categories") or die(mysqli_error($con));
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $question = mysqli_query($con, "select * from question where cat_id='".$id."' ") or die(mysqli_error($con));   
                ?>  
        <fieldset>
           <input type="hidden" name="cat_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
             <div class="card" style="background-color: #fff; " > 
             <div class="card-body" style="margin-left: 20px;">
             <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <?php 
          while ($question_row = mysqli_fetch_array($question)) {
         ?>
           <input type="hidden" name="question_id[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>">     
        <div class="form-group">
         <label style="font-weight: 900;">
           <strong>
            <?php echo $question_row['question']; ?>
           </strong>
         </label>
        <br>
        <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="5" required>
        <label class="form-check-label">
            Strongly Agree
        </label>
       </div>
    <br>
        <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="4" required>
    <label class="form-check-label">
        Agree
    </label>
</div>
    <br>
    

    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="3" required>
        <label class="form-check-label">
        Neutral
        </label>
        </div>
       <br>
        <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="2" required>
        <label class="form-check-label">
            Disgree
        </label>
       </div>
         <br>
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="1" required>
            <label class="form-check-label">
              Strongly Disagree
            </label>
        </div>
        <br>
        </div>
       <?php } ?>
      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
              <?php if($m!=$count){ ?>
                <button name="" id="" class="btn btn-primary next-form btn-sm" type="button" style="background-color: #fff200; color:#000;">
                 Next
                 </button>
                <?php } if($m!=1){ ?>
                 <button name="" id="" class="btn btn-warning previous-form" type="button">
                  Previous
                 </button>
                <?php } ?>
                 <?php if($m==$count){ ?>
                    <button  class="btn btn-info submit" id="submit_form">
                       Submit
                    </button>
                    <?php } ?>
          </fieldset>
             <?php
                    $m++;
         }
         ?>
      </form>
```

**UPDATE!!!**

I removed the class for the button bootstrap. Now it validates if the option is not selected. Now my problem is, even if the first set of questions are all answered, it cannot go to the next page when button is clicked.

**UPDATE 2**
I think this is because of this script

```
  $(document).ready(function(){  
  var form_count = 1, previous_form, next_form, total_forms;
  total_forms = $("fieldset").length;  
  $(".next-form").click(function(){
        previous_form = $(this).parent();
        next_form = $(this).parent().next();
        next_form.show();
        previous_form.hide();
        setProgressBarValue(++form_count);
  });
```

How will I do now?

Comment: Please edit your code to fix the indentation to make it more readable. Are you able to use javasctipt?

Comment: Buttons of `type=button` do not trigger in-browser validation. For your "Next" button you will need to use javascript. The `required` attribute should be sufficient for actual form submit and browser validation.

Comment: Hi! I tried javascript as you said. But there is still something wrong, yes it checks if the radio button is selected, but still it goes to next page. 

with this code
`function atLeastOneRadio()
{
 return($('input[type=radio]:checked').size()>0);
}`

Answer (score 1):

(1) If you want to user cannot submit without answer, you should add **required** on the radio button.
(2) If you want to allow the user submit without answer, I think it's running well.
But due to Bootstrap, it should be:

```
 <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="5">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        Strongly Agree
      </label>
    </div>
<div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>][<?php echo $question_row['id'] ?>]" value="4">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        Agree
      </label>
    </div>
```

If you have any additional info, please kindly let me know.

Comment: in my form, the user must answer every question. it must not be blank. what happens with my code is, even if the questions are not answered, it can still be submitted. I tried adding required in the radio button but it does not work. The form must be filled up first before submit. each question should have 1 radio button checked.

Comment: I afraid it's because your radio button is wrapped in Label.
Please try to separate them.

Comment: I tried to separate them now, but still when next button is clicked even if there are no answers it still submits

Comment: I edited my post, and now I think maybe the buttons are the wrong here.

Comment: Sorry for confirmation.
Every question is on one form or not?
Required is working when submitting in form .
The button should be auto type=Submit when wrapped in a form.
If you possible, would you mind to share to us? Your complete form?

Comment: the questions are saved in a database, and loaded through while loop. So that in every next button, questions will be different. I will be updating my question and show my whole form code. Thank you very much for helping

Comment: I see your last edited post. I think required is not working because your button is type="button".
You can use JavaScript for validation.
Use on click event on "next button " and validate it.

Comment: I edited my post again and this time with the whole code for the form. Thanks I will try that.

Comment: I updated again on my progress, it seems like the script is the problem now. Even if the questions are all answered, next button cannot be clicked.